# Animations are not being killed on backgroundView of the UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uiviewanimation

**Update:**

1. I have a UITableView which loads data from a web service.
2. While it's loading data, I'm setting its backgroundView to UIAnyCustomView (subclass of UIView), which I draw programmatically and animate it.
3. After I receive the data from the web service, I set UITableView's backgroundView to nil as it is optional, where I think the animations should be removed automatically, but they're not.

**My question: Why?**

**Original Question (updated for clarification)**

I've received some battery usage feedbacks for one of my apps. I used xCode instruments to monitor battery usage and found the issue. I was setting backgroundView of the UITableView/UICollectionView statically which was calling animation forever (let's call it UICustomeActivityIndicator):

```
fileprivate func rotateLoadingView() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveLinear], animations: {
        self.innerCircleView.transform = self.innerCircleView.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(M_PI_2))
    }) { result in
        if !self.isHidden {
            self.rotateLoadingView()
        }
    }
}
```

Then, when the content was loaded I was clearing backgroundView by setting it to nil:

```
// collectionView.backgroundView = nil
tableView.backgroundView = nil
```

But even if I was clearing the backgroundView, the animation was still going on and it was using huge battery (also while sending the application to the background).

My question; Is this behaviour normal or it's bug of the backgroundView UITableView/UICollectionView and it should be cleared automatically while it has been set to nil?

Comment: Are you doing `activityIndicator.hidden = true` anywhere in the controller? Why do you think that setting `backgroundView` to nil would affect `activityView`?

Comment: Yes I do set activityIndicator.hidden = true. When I set backgroundView to nil, why shouldn't it effect the activityView? System should remove it's animations automatically, right?

Answer (score 2):

You're wrong to think that removing a view from hierarchy will cause animations to be cancelled by the system. A view may be added to a superview or not, but in any case you can run animations on it unless the object is completely deallocated. So since you're strongly referencing `indicatorView` in a controller, it is still alive and there is no reason for your animations to be removed.

I would recommend to avoid recursive method. You can achieve the result you need by two methods in your custom activity indicator:

```
func startAnimation() {
    let rotateAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
    rotateAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
    rotateAnimation.toValue = CGFloat(M_PI * 2.0)
    rotateAnimation.duration = 1
    rotateAnimation.repeatCount = .infinity

    layer.add(rotateAnimation, forKey: nil)
}

func stopRotation() {
    layer.removeAllAnimations()
}
```

Now just call `start` and `stop` whenever you need in your controller and you won't have any issues as you described.

Comment: Please do not go outside of the question. Even if my approach is wrong while calling animation recursively, when I set backgroundView to nil, system should remove it's animations automatically, right? I want to clarify this case with the question.

Comment: Your question doesn't clarify how actually your activity indicator is related to backgroundView. Is it a subview of backgroundView or what?

Comment: @alexburtnik It's an extension of an UIView which has any animation (no matter animating recursively like mine or yours). When I set the backgroundView to nil, it should be cleared, right? Why it's continuing to animate in the background?

Comment: No, it should not be cleared. IndicatorView is still alive and it's recursive method is still running no matter what you do with `backgroundView`.

Comment: @alexburtnik Any explanation (reference or clarification why?) on that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't want to specify details about your view hierarchy which I asked for, so I cannot even understand your logic why you expect that behavior at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126722/discussion-between-rashid-and-alexburtnik).

Answer (score 1):

Removing the view won't remove the animation, because animations are added in the UIView layer. Setting the view to nil wont change the layer properties. Removing the view you only remove the visible part not the layer properties. That's why animations are running in the background. for remove all animations in view layer by calling removeAllAnimations()

```
view.layer.removeAllAnimations()
```

Comment: Animations are added in the view layer, by removing the view can't remove the animation. if you want to stop that you have to remove the animation from the layer.

Comment: My opinion: when we set the optional backgroundView to nil, it should be removed. So non-existing view cannot be animated, right?

Comment: No.Thats the difference between the layer and UIView, here we are setting animation to the layer not to the view. by removing the view, you only remove the visible part not the layer properties thats should be handled separately.